# How to bind angular directive to kendo ui model

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I have searched plenty and cannot find a similar problem and solution online, but I have been banging my head against the wall for too long...

I  want to pass through the angular model/object through to the directive, so that when it returns a new element, it is bound to the old model/object...
Currently it is returning the value
I have tried to keep the code as simple and straight forward as possible...

Hope this makes sense:

Directive:

```
(function () {
    angular.module('myMod').directive('myDir', ['$compile',
        function ($compile) {
            return {
                restrict: 'E',
                replace: true,
                scope: {
                    type: '@',
                    val: '@'
                },
                link: function (scope, element, attrs) {                
                    var newEl;                   
                    switch (scope.type) {
                        case "1":
                            newEl = '<input type="text" class="k-textbox" k-ng-model="{{val}}"  />';
                            break;
                        case "2":
                            newEl = '<input kendo-date-picker k-ng-model="{{val}}" />';
                            break;
                    }
                    element.replaceWith($compile(newEl)(scope));

                }
            };
        }
    ]);
})();
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="item in vm.model.things">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <label class="control-label">{{item.name}}</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <my-dir type="{{item.type}}" value="{{item.val}}" ></my-dir>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I inspect the element I can see it's returning the value: "*This is a textbox*", I am sure I am close but instead of the value/text, I want to "bind" the model/object to the directive:

```
<input type="text" class="k-textbox ng-scope" k-ng-model="This is a textbox text">
```

Please feel free to edit the question if you understand what I am trying to achieve and it helps make more sense for others...
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using interpolation directive there, it will add evaluated value in `value` attribute, rather use `val` directly so that `k-ng-model` will keep reference of `val` $scope value reference

```
switch (scope.type) {
    case "1":
        newEl = '<input type="text" class="k-textbox" k-ng-model="val"  />';
        break;
    case "2":
        newEl = '<input kendo-date-picker k-ng-model="val" />';
        break;
}
```